# flask app runs locally but crashes when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn

I have a flask app crashing when deploying to Heroku that runs fine locally with the exact same command in Procfile `gunicorn wsgi:app`

Relevant heroku log:

```
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529605+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529605+00:00 app[web.1]:     app = create_app()
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529606+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 15, in create_app
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529606+00:00 app[web.1]:     from . import routes
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529606+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/routes.py", line 6, in <module>
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529606+00:00 app[web.1]:     from package.reservation_factory import ReservationFactory
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529606+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/package/reservation_factory.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529607+00:00 app[web.1]:     from package.provider import ProviderReservation
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529607+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/package/provider.py", line 12, in <module>
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529607+00:00 app[web.1]:     from package.reservation import Reservation
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529608+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.reservation'
2021-02-02T00:10:31.529902+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-02 00:10:31 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
```

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       └── reservation.html
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── provider.py
│   ├── reservation.py
│   └── reservation_factory.py
├── runtime.txt
└── wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your project structure is the missing top level `__init__.py` file. This file is necessary to make a Python package, from which you can import.

While not mandatory, many projects go with a `src` layout, like the following:

```
❯ tree src/
src/
└── reservation_app
    ├── app
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── routes.py
    │   └── templates
    ├── __init__.py
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── provider.py
        ├── reservation_factory.py
        └── reservation.py

4 directories, 8 files
```

You'd need to adjust your imports, though.

If you want to read more about why a `src` layout is a good thing, have a look at these blog posts

https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/
https://web.archive.org/web/20170615032800/https://enotuniq.org/
https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/08/test-as-installed.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately, Heroku still crashes with the same error after adding an `__init__.py` to the top level. Also, the missing module comes from the call `from package.provider import ProviderReservation` which comes from another call  `from package.reservation_factory import ReservationFactory`, both inside of the same `package` directory. Doesn't that imply the app is already able to find the directory?

Comment: Could you please show you new directory structure? You can't do a from package.provider import smth.. you have to do a `from xxx.package.provider.reservation_factory import ReservationFactory`-> so always from the top level. Is your app available on GitHub? Then I could have a look. Otherwise try to follow my schema, and first make sure it works locally. (Disclamier: I never used Heroku, but I created quite some Flask applications and deployed them to production).

Comment: It always worked fine locally, the issue was with the Heroku deployment. Regardless I was messing around and changed the name of file and import from `reservation` to `reservations` and it works now ‍♂️

Comment: DO NOT TOUCH IT ANY MORE! :-D Any way, glad to hear its working.